# C, How to acess a structure from another structure?

Tags: c

I am getting an error:

```
error: request for member ‘clsf_ptr’ in something not a structure or union
```

From this C Program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define M 3

struct class_stud
{
    char name[16];
    char subject[16];
    int roll_num;
}

struct node
{
    int n;
    struct branch *p[M];
    struct class_stud cls[M-1];
}*root=NULL;

main()
{
    int clsf_cnt;
    struct class_stud clsf, *clsf_ptr;
    clsf_ptr = &clsf;
    clsf_cnt = 0;
    root = malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    printf("enter source address \n");
    scanf("%s",&root.clsf_ptr[clsf_cnt]->name);
    printf("%s",root.clsf_ptr[clsf_cnt]->name);

    printf("enter key\n");
    scanf("%d",&root.clsf_ptr[clsf_cnt]->key);
    printf("%d",root.clsf_ptr[clsf_cnt] -> key);
    clsf_cnt++;
}
```

What does the error mean?

Comment: Paste the exact error message or compiler output so we can help you better.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of problems in this code.  Let's walk through it line by line:

```
#include<stdio.h>     
#define M 3      

struct class_stud     
{     
  char name[16];     
  char subject[16];     
  int roll_num;     
}
```

First problem; you need a closing `;` after the struct definition above.  Also, it's interesting that you don't define a preprocessor macro for the lengths of the `name` and `subject` arrays, but that's a minor issue at this point.

```
struct node     
{     
  int n;     
  struct branch *p[M];     
  struct class_stud cls[M-1];     
}*root=NULL;
```

Where is the definition for `struct branch`?  What is `p` supposed to represent in the structure definition?  Why do you have one fewer elements in `cls` than `p`?

```
main()
```

As of C99, you cannot get away with an implicit type for `main`; it must be explicitly typed to return `int`.  And, since you're not messing with any command-line arguments, it's best to explicitly set the parameter list to `void`, like so:

```
int main(void)
{     
  int clsf_cnt;     
  struct class_stud clsf, *clsf_ptr;     
  clsf_ptr = &clsf;
```

What purpose does the above operation serve?

```
  clsf_cnt = 0;     
  root = malloc(sizeof (struct node));
```

That's fine, but a preferred way of writing this would be

```
  root = malloc(sizeof *root);
```

That way you're sure to allocate the right amount of memory based on `root`'s type.

```
  printf("enter source address \n");     
  scanf("%s",&root.clsf_ptr[clsf_cnt]->name);
```

Ack.  Multiple problems in this one line.

First of all, `clsf_ptr` is *not* a member of `struct node`.  You likely meant to access `cls`.  Secondly, since `root` is a pointer to struct, you need to use the `->` operator to access its members (or explicitly dereference `root` and then use `.`).  Third, `cls[clsf_cnt]` is *not* a pointer type, so you would use the `.` operator to access `name`.  Finally, since `name` is an array type, it will implicitly be converted to a pointer type before being passed to `scanf`, so the `&` isn't necessary.

In order to avoid buffer overflow, you should either put a maximum field width in the `%s` conversion specifier, or use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`.

Sticking with `scanf()`, that line should be written as

```
  scanf("%15s", root->cls[clsf_cnt].name);
```

I'm using 15 instead of 16 in the conversion specifier so that we leave one character for the 0 terminator.

Using fgets(), that line would be written

```
  fgets(root->cls[clsf_cnt].name, sizeof root->cls[clsf_cnt].name, stdin);
  printf("%s",root.clsf_ptr[clsf_cnt]->name);
```

Again, you're trying to access something that isn't a member of `root`, and you have your access operators backwards:

```
  printf ("%s", root->cls[clsf_cnt].name);

  printf("enter key\n");     
  scanf("%d",&root.clsf_ptr[clsf_cnt]->key);     
  printf("%d",root.clsf_ptr[clsf_cnt] -> key);
```

`struct class_stud` has no member named `key`; perhaps you meant `roll_num`?

```
  scanf("%d", &root->cls[clsf_cnt].roll_num);
  printf("%d", root->cls[clsf_cnt].roll_num);    
  clsf_cnt++;     
}
```

It looks like you've posted something that isn't complete; make sure you're showing us the same code you're trying to build.

Answer (score 1):

Any instance of `root.clsf_ptr` you have in your code should be replaced with `root->clsf_ptr`, which indicates that `root` is a pointer to a struct.

You also need to make sure the member `clsf_ptr` is located in the `node` struct.

Comment: i changed it to      printf("enter source address \n");
scanf("%s",&root->clsf_ptr[clsf_cnt]->name);
printf("%s",root->clsf_ptr[clsf_cnt]->name);
i still get same error with error: invalid type argument of ‘->’
printf("enter key\n");
scanf("%d",&root->clsf_ptr[clsf_cnt]->key);
printf("%d",root->clsf_ptr[clsf_cnt] -> key)                                                           ‘struct node’ has no member named ‘clsf_ptr’

Comment: @stident: That's because it doesn't. From your code, it looks like name should be `cls`. Also there is no member named `key`, which you reference near the end of the code.

Comment: @stident - Can you also edit your code example to reflect your recent changes? I immediately saw the same thing that @Tim Cooper did and was about to post an answer until I saw his.

Comment: @Tim Cooper - I took a wild guess that `key` should be a signed integer in `class_stud` from the formatting arguments in scanf().

Answer (score 1):

Here is some general source code cleanup that may be helpful:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M 3

typedef struct
{
  char  name [16];
  char  subject [16];
  int   roll_num;

} Class_stud;


typedef struct
{
  int         n;
  Branch*     p[M];
  Class_stud  cls[M-1];

} Node;



int main()
{
  Node*        root;
  int          clsf_cnt;
  Class_stud   clsf;
  Class_stud*  clsf_ptr;

  clsf_ptr = &clsf;
  clsf_cnt = 0;

  root = malloc (sizeof(Node));

  if(root == NULL)
  {
    /* error handling here */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you. I'm *assuming* `key` should be a member in `class_stud` (and by your formatting options in scanf, a signed integer):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define M 3

typedef struct
{
    char name[16];
    char subject[16];
    int roll_num;
    int key;
} class_stud;

typedef struct
{
    int n;
    struct branch *p[M];
    struct class_stud cls[M-1];
} node;

int main(void)
{
    int clsf_cnt = 0;
    node *root;

    root = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (root == NULL) {
       /* handle error */
    }

    printf("enter source address \n");
    scanf("%s",&root->cls[clsf_cnt]->name);
    printf("%s",root->cls[clsf_cnt]->name);

    printf("enter key\n");
    scanf("%d",&root->cls[clsf_cnt]->key);
    printf("%d",root->cls[clsf_cnt]->key);
    clsf_cnt++;
}
```

You had the following problems:

- Incorrectly accessing class_stud. It's a part of root, so you want root -> class_stud[member]->value.
- `key` was omitted
- Both were changed to typedefined structures as shown in [Lundin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828812/how-to-acess-a-structure-from-another-structure/4828948#4828948) answer, however you need not make them types (just using struct is fine).
- We just declare root to be a pointer to node, rather than declaring struct node, and then a pointer and then making the assignment.
- We aren't creating a structure as a pointer, we're creating a pointer to a structure
- Main should return the type `int`, if you don't want arguments, tell the compiler that you expect argc to be void.

Stuff I didn't do:

- Initialize the allocated structure with memset() or via calloc()
- Handle malloc() failing
- Compile my example (I don't know what struct branch is)

Answer (score -3):

I think malloc syntax is wrong. once check that. Memory is not allocated.Thats why it shows an error.

Comment: malloc syntax is perfectly right and idiomatic. Casting from a pointer to void is not required in C.

Comment: The OP had two problems, incorrectly dereferencing the allocated structure and had missing members. While I do cast the return of malloc() if writing something that has to be portable to c++, it is not required in C as @Alexandre explained.